# How to configure security for Mosquitto with Godaddy certificates

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, mqtt

I am able to configure security with the openssl certificates. But with the Godaddy certificates, I could not configure the secure mosquitto.
I got 3 files from Godaddy SSL,

1. 2324145e73d34dad.crt
2. 2324145e73d34dad.pem
3. gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

As per the Godaddy site, the 1st one is Root certificate i.e ca.crt
3rd one is the intermediate / chain certificate.

But I want the server.crt and server.key to configure.

How can we configure the ssl with those files? Can we generate the server.key and server.crt with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the private key encoding.
When we download the private key from GoDaddy, it is in UTF-8-BOM encoding, we need to change the Encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You should already have the private key, you needed to use it to generate the CSR you sent to Godaddy to get the certificate signed.

`2324145e73d34dad.pem` sounds like it's your server certificate (which is what mosquitto wants)

From the man page:

> **certfile** *file path*
>
> Path to the PEM encoded server certificate. This option and keyfile must be present to enable certificate based TLS encryption.

Comment: I used the following conf   cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/2324145e73d34dad.pem
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/privatekey.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt but got the error  Error: Unable to load server key file "/etc/mosquitto/certs/privatekey.key". Check keyfile.

Comment: As you've not supplied any information about the `privatekey.key` file I can't really help, but I would guess you haven't removed the password from it.

Comment: I don't know what password attached to that privatekey but able to access that with the root user

Comment: Again, **if** there is a password, you must know it, because it was used to generate the CSR, but as I've said, you've not supplied any information about the keyfile so the best we can do is guess

Comment: I have the private key and CSR files too. I used the same private key as the server key in mqtt config. But I don't know what was the password phrase in the private key.

Comment: If there is a password and you can't remember the password, then you'll have to start again from scratch, there is no way to use that keyfile without knowing what it is.

Comment: Why do we need that password? I have done earlier with openssl generated ssl certificates and it worked well and never used the password once I generated the server certificates and client certificates. I just placed in the etc/mosquitto/certs directory. Why is it behaving differently now.

Comment: Note, that I said **IF** the key has a password you will need to remove it. As I have already said, without access to all the information all I can do is guess. And I'm done with guessing now.

Comment: Ok, I used the autogenerated Private Key and CSR to create the Certificate in Godaddy. Later I saved the privatekey and CSR and downloaded the generated certificates. The generated certificates zip file contains these 3 files 2324145e73d34dad.crt
2324145e73d34dad.pem
gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt